# How to get the formatted autonumber value in MS Access to appear in form control as a formatted value?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an ID field with an AutoNumber Data Type that has a custom format defined in the Field Properties (A-00001, A-00002, etc).

I wanted to look up the formatted value and display it in a form textbox control.

ServiceNumber_entry = DLookup("ServiceID", "ServiceRecord", "SNID = '" & Forms!ServiceEntry!PartSN_entry & "'")

Using the line above, it returns just the number value and not the full formatted value (i.e. 1 instead of A-00001). What am I missing?

Comment: I'm assuming that the issue stems from the AutoNumber being a Long Integer so the format isn't captured with the DLookup function.

Comment: A format is, well, just a format. You'll have to set up a format on form level too. Having said that, the sole and only sole purpose of an autonumber is to uniquely identify records. You should not apply additional purposes and/or show it outside your table. Create your own sequential data if you have to (f.i. an invoice number, purchase order number, item number, et cetera).

Comment: Defining the format in the field properties, you did not "format the values", instead you told Access to format the values whenever this field is displayed. Using DLookup in a Textbox, you don't display the field, you display a calculated value.

Comment: If you have to display it formatted, just lookup the format in the tabledef and put it to the displaying control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing comments all contain good information, but it can be useful to put it all together.  The comments also failed to describe the context in which Access automatically copies and applies properties like Format, so that the comments (even if correct) might seem contradictory.  My explanation is a bit verbose, but hopefully avoids further confusion.

The purpose of the *Format* property for any value in Access is to define *how the data is displayed*.  This is true of a table column presented in a datasheet or a textbox control on a form.  The Format does *not* define how values are stored, either in storage or in memory.  The same value could be formatted and displayed differently without affecting the underlying stored datum.  In this case, the Autonumber values are really Long Integer values.  (They are *not* stored with a preceding "A-", which would require the values to be strings and would ruin Access's ability to automatically increment the values.)

Access attempts to provide a consistent view of the data and reduce tedious programming details by automatically copying the Format property to queries and form controls, just as it does with many other metadata properties.  For instance, if you drag the AutoNumber field onto a form in design mode, it will automatically copy the Format string from the column to the TextBox control's Format property.  In contrast, if you include the same column in a query, the query's column property sheet also has a Format property, but it will remain blank by default.  However, when the query is executed, it will indeed be displayed with the format defined on the table column.  This behavior does not mean that the data values themselves "have a format", rather Access is just doing its automatic work of looking up default formatting values from the table definition and applying it to the query's output.  (It can do this if there is a simple one-to-one table column to query column relation, which is the usual case for queries.)

DLookup() is a Visual Basic (VBA) function.  It is necessary that such functions handle the "raw" data independently of metadata, like Format (or Caption, Text Alignment, etc.).  For coding purposes, a programmer expects to retrieve the actual long integer value from the column, not a formatted string value like "A-00001".  The function will not only skip the format, the formatting information is completely dropped from data values.  In a programming environment, data can be combined and manipulated and the concept of "format" becomes lost and/or meaningless.  Even though in this case it might seem obvious, DLookup makes no assumptions about what you're going to do with the data and so just returns the integer values.

If your form TextBox control was not originally placed on the form specifically for the AutoNumber field, Access would not know to the copy the Format property.  It would just display the integers from DLookup() as basic integers.  However, you can manually set the TextBox's Format property to match the table column's Format property exactly to get back the expected values.

Comment: For what its worth, Rene's warning about using formats on the AutoNumber fields should be considered.  You may find scenarios in the future where you actually do have text data storing values like "A-0005", requiring the text to be parsed and converted to an integer for comparison to the original field.  This may or may not be a big problem, but something to consider... amongst other issues.